# How to ignore field for JAX-RS web service in Spring boot

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-mvc, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I created an XML file using jersey pluging. The data retreive sucessfully and it returns all of the class.

I want to customize the fields of my model. Which annotaion can I use for this for ignore feild?

**I want to remove dtIssue,appPostdate feilds from XML**

My model is

```
package lk.slsi.domain;


import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CustomsPermit")
@XmlRootElement(name = "Permits")
public class CustomsPermit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "permit_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, name = "EntryNumber")
    private String SNumber;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, name = "Application_ID")
    private String applicationID;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "PermitReleaseDate")
    private String appPostdate;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String dtIssue;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "PostedUserId")
    private String userID;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String cusdecNo;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String importerVAT;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String importerDetails;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String invoiceNo;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String invoiceValue;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String totQty;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String UoM;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String hsCod;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String productDesc;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String blNo;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String cond1;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String cond2;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String cond3;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String cond4;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String cond5;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String cond6;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSNumber() {
        return SNumber;
    }

    public void setSNumber(String SNumber) {
        this.SNumber = SNumber;
    }

    public String getApplicationID() {
        return applicationID;
    }

    public void setApplicationID(String applicationID) {
        this.applicationID = applicationID;
    }

    public String getAppPostdate() {
        return appPostdate;
    }

    public void setAppPostdate(String appPostdate) {
        this.appPostdate = appPostdate;
    }

    public String getDtIssue() {
        return dtIssue;
    }

    public void setDtIssue(String dtIssue) {
        this.dtIssue = dtIssue;
    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getCusdecNo() {
        return cusdecNo;
    }

    public void setCusdecNo(String cusdecNo) {
        this.cusdecNo = cusdecNo;
    }

    public String getImporterVAT() {
        return importerVAT;
    }

    public void setImporterVAT(String importerVAT) {
        this.importerVAT = importerVAT;
    }

    public String getImporterDetails() {
        return importerDetails;
    }

    public void setImporterDetails(String importerDetails) {
        this.importerDetails = importerDetails;
    }

    public String getInvoiceNo() {
        return invoiceNo;
    }

    public void setInvoiceNo(String invoiceNo) {
        this.invoiceNo = invoiceNo;
    }

    public String getInvoiceValue() {
        return invoiceValue;
    }

    public void setInvoiceValue(String invoiceValue) {
        this.invoiceValue = invoiceValue;
    }

    public String getTotQty() {
        return totQty;
    }

    public void setTotQty(String totQty) {
        this.totQty = totQty;
    }

    public String getUoM() {
        return UoM;
    }

    public void setUoM(String UoM) {
        this.UoM = UoM;
    }

    public String getHsCod() {
        return hsCod;
    }

    public void setHsCod(String hsCod) {
        this.hsCod = hsCod;
    }

    public String getProductDesc() {
        return productDesc;
    }

    public void setProductDesc(String productDesc) {
        this.productDesc = productDesc;
    }

    public String getBlNo() {
        return blNo;
    }

    public void setBlNo(String blNo) {
        this.blNo = blNo;
    }

    public String getCond1() {
        return cond1;
    }

    public void setCond1(String cond1) {
        this.cond1 = cond1;
    }

    public String getCond2() {
        return cond2;
    }

    public void setCond2(String cond2) {
        this.cond2 = cond2;
    }

    public String getCond3() {
        return cond3;
    }

    public void setCond3(String cond3) {
        this.cond3 = cond3;
    }

    public String getCond4() {
        return cond4;
    }

    public void setCond4(String cond4) {
        this.cond4 = cond4;
    }

    public String getCond5() {
        return cond5;
    }

    public void setCond5(String cond5) {
        this.cond5 = cond5;
    }

    public String getCond6() {
        return cond6;
    }

    public void setCond6(String cond6) {
        this.cond6 = cond6;
    }
}
```

**How to ignore dtIssue,appPostdate feilds from XML**

Comment: This is not dublicate... I searched from stackoverflow.. But i didn't find that anything about it

Comment: Did you try by giving @XmlTransient  for the properties you want to ignore?

Comment: any success with above link?

Comment: @pallapothu how to do that

Comment: Please take a look at [mcve] and try to shorten your code.

Comment: @waroop .... XmlTransient  works fine